# PowerBI Table Visual: Totals as SUM instead of Average

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a possibly simple question about table visuals in PowerBI.
From the image, you can see that some of my columns get assigned with the SUM and some of them get assigned with the Average.

[image]

From the selection pane, I am only able to change the font and color.
Is there a way to change the type of aggregation?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not at the formatting pane, but where you add your data to the table visual, right-click on the relevant numerical column and you'll see a number of summarization options. To me, but default 'Sum' is selected, but you can adjust it individually for each column.